# java enum and postgresql enum

Tags: java, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE customers
(
  first_name character varying(15),
  second_name character varying(20),
  login character varying(15) NOT NULL,
  password character varying(15),
  email character varying(40),
  gender gender,
  register_date date,
  date_of_birth date,
  address character varying(40),
  address_number integer,
  town character varying(20),
  CONSTRAINT login PRIMARY KEY (login)
)
```

I have this table and I created an enum of gender such as:

```
CREATE TYPE gender AS ENUM ( 'F', 'M',);
```

I am trying to insert into customers data from eclipse java with PreparedStatement
but there is an error such as ERROR: column "gender" is of type gender but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

My Java code looks like:

```
PreparedStatement pre_state;

public enum gendertype {
    F,
    M;
}

pre_state = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO"
            + " customers VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
pre_state.set(6, gendertype.F.toString());
```

Comment: It's probably inserting it as `'F'::text`, which would cause the error.

Comment: ok i found as solution and it works

Comment: pre_state=main.conne.conn.prepareStatement("insert into customers values (?,?,?,?,?,?::gender,?,?,?,?,?)");

Comment: pre_state.setString(6,gendertype.F.toString());

Comment: Please consider adding an `Other` and/or `unspecified` value for `gender`. Gender isn't simply two values; you have genetically XXY individuals, developmentally intersex individuals, etc. Like assuming that names has a "first name" and "surname" it's a bad habit in computing that needs to go away.

Comment: @CraigRinger that's an excellent point. I know someone who has only one name, which is "LynC". Her drivers licence has a dot as her first name... etc. Don't be too prescriptive with data

Answer (score 15):

I can take no credit for this answer as you have already solved it,  but I will explain why it works.

PostgreSQL  provides the answer when it says

> Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression

The Java code is creating a string literal value that represents  the Java enum gendertype type.

Casting a literal to a PostgreSQL  gender type is done by adding a casting suffix to the value `::gender`.

So valid input would be

```
'F'::gender
```

or

```
'M'::gender
```

This works because all PostgreSQL types have a input method that takes a text representation and converts that to the internal form.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution would have been

```
pre_state.setObject(6, gendertype.F.toString(), Types.OTHER);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers if you use for example `createNativeQuery()` you should cast value to your `enum` like `cast(? as gender)`, something like that:

```
Person person = new Person("Gurbanguly", "Berdymukhamedov", Gender.Male)
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
session.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO Person (firstname, lastname, gender) VALUES (?,?,cast(? as gender))")
            .setParameter(1, person.getFirstName())
            .setParameter(2, person.getLastName())
            .setParameter(3, person.getGender().toString())
            .executeUpdate();
transaction.commit();
session.close(); // this statement is needed not to produce many sessions
```