# R2DBC and enum (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, enums, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

**Update 15/08/2020:** Looks like `Enum` support was added on Jun 16. [R2DBC commit](https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql/commit/6e642f57beae1800afb88a28787be1b2f2bb0570).

Does H2DBC support PostgreSQL enums? I checked they [git page](https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-postgresql#data-type-mapping) but it doesn't mention anything about it. If it does, how enums could be used (INSERT, SELECT)?
Lets say PostgreSQL enum

```sql
CREATE TYPE mood AS ENUM ('UNKNOWN', 'HAPPY', 'SAD', ...);
```

Java class

```java
@Data
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Mood mood;
    // ...

    enum Mood{ UNKNOWN, HAPPY, SAD, ...}
}
```

I tried:

```java
        // insert
        var person = ...;
        client.insert()
                .table("people")
                .using(person)
                .then()
                .subscribe(System.out::println);

        // select
        var query = "SELECT * FROM people";
        client.execute(query)
                .as(Person.class)
                .fetch().all()
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

But I'm getting error messages:

```sh
# on insert
 WARN [reactor-tcp-epoll-1] (Loggers.java:294) - Error: SEVERITY_LOCALIZED=ERROR, SEVERITY_NON_LOCALIZED=ERROR, CODE=42804, MESSAGE=column "mood" is of type mood but expression is of type character varying, HINT=You will need to rewrite or cast the expression., POSITION=61, FILE=parse_target.c, LINE=591, ROUTINE=transformAssignedExpr
# on select
ERROR [reactor-tcp-epoll-1] (Loggers.java:319) - [id: 0x8581acdb, L:/127.0.0.1:39726 ! R:127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:5432] Error was received while reading the incoming data. The connection will be closed.
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Could not read property private ...
```

I found [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492370/java-enum-and-postgresql-enum) but without luck to solve my problem.. maybe I was applying it wrong..
Any help or tips are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

Tested with `org.springframework.data:spring-data-r2dbc:1.0.0.RELEASE` and `io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql:0.8.1.RELEASE`.

**Kotlin version.**

1. Define a enum class

   ```kotlin
   enum class Mood {
       UNKNOWN,
       HAPPY,
       SAD
   }
   ```
2. Create a custom codec

   ```kotlin
   class MoodCodec(private val allocator: ByteBufAllocator) :  Codec<Mood> {
       override fun canEncodeNull(type: Class<*>): Boolean = false

       override fun canEncode(value: Any): Boolean = value is Mood

       override fun encode(value: Any): Parameter {
           return Parameter(Format.FORMAT_TEXT, oid) {
               ByteBufUtils.encode(allocator, (value as Mood).name)
           }
       }

       override fun canDecode(dataType: Int, format: Format, type: Class<*>): Boolean = dataType == oid

       override fun decode(buffer: ByteBuf?, dataType: Int, format: Format, type: Class<out Mood>): Mood? {
           buffer ?: return null
           return Mood.valueOf(ByteBufUtils.decode(buffer))
       }

       override fun type(): Class<*> = Mood::class.java

       override fun encodeNull(): Parameter =
           Parameter(Format.FORMAT_TEXT, oid, Parameter.NULL_VALUE)

       companion object {
           // Get form `select oid from pg_type where typname = 'mood'`
           private const val oid = YOUR_ENUM_OID
       }
   }
   ```
3. Registe the codec

   You may need change `runtimeOnly("io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql")` to `implementation("io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql")`

   ```kotlin
   @Configuration
   @EnableR2dbcRepositories
   class AppConfig : AbstractR2dbcConfiguration() {
       override fun connectionFactory(): ConnectionFactory = PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
           .port(5432) // Add your config here.
           .codecRegistrar { _, allocator, registry ->
               registry.addFirst(MoodCodec(allocator))
               Mono.empty()
           }.build()
           .let { PostgresqlConnectionFactory(it) }
   }
   ```

Comment: R2dbc Postgres driver includes a built-in `EnumCodec` to support `enum` type in Postgres.

Comment: Hi @Hantsy, how about enum support for another kind of databases (such as oracle, mssql, etc)

Comment: Hi @Hantsy, could you help to re answer?

Answer (score 5):

I used the below for Spring boot 2.6.4 + r2dbc-postgresql 0.8.11 by adding a customizer rather than creating the connection factory myself.

Thanks @Hantsy for pointing EnumCodec out. I added it to a customizer therefore it can play nicely with existing autoconfigure procedure. Also, the spring-data keeps converting my enum to string until I added the converter.

Hopefully these can provide a little help to others.

1. Register EnumCodec to builder customizer as extensions

   It is possible to register multiple enum, just repeat the withEnum() call.

```
  /**
   * Use the customizer to add EnumCodec to R2DBC
   */
  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactoryOptionsBuilderCustomizer connectionFactoryOptionsBuilderCustomizer() {
    return builder -> {
      builder.option(Option.valueOf("extensions"),
                     List.of(EnumCodec.builder()
                       .withEnum("enum_foo", FooEnum.class)
                       .withRegistrationPriority(RegistrationPriority.FIRST)
                       .build()));

      logger.info("Adding enum to R2DBC postgresql extensions: {}", builder);
    };
  }
```

2. Implement spring data converter by extending EnumWriteSupport

```
public class FooWritingConverter extends EnumWriteSupport<Foo> {
}
```

3. Register converters so that spring data won't always convert enum to string.

   This step is a slightly enhanced version of R2dbcDataAutoConfiguration in spring-boot-autoconfigure project.

```
  /**
   * Register converter to make sure Spring data treat enum correctly
   */
  @Bean
  public R2dbcCustomConversions r2dbcCustomConversions(DatabaseClient databaseClient) {
    logger.info("Apply R2DBC custom conversions");
    R2dbcDialect dialect = DialectResolver.getDialect(databaseClient.getConnectionFactory());
    List<Object> converters = new ArrayList<>(dialect.getConverters());
    converters.addAll(R2dbcCustomConversions.STORE_CONVERTERS);
    return new R2dbcCustomConversions(
      CustomConversions.StoreConversions.of(dialect.getSimpleTypeHolder(), converters),
      List.of(
        new FooWritingConverter()
      ));
  }
```

Step 1 and 3 can be added to your application class or any other valid configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Check [my article](https://medium.com/@hantsy/dealing-with-postgres-specific-json-enum-type-and-notifier-listener-with-r2dbc-f15cc104aa10) about Postgres specific features supported in R2dbc.

There are two options.

1. use custom Postgres enum type and Java enum type, and register `EnumCodec` in the connection factory builder.
2. use a textual type as data type(such as varchar), and Java Enum type, Spring data r2dbc will convert them directly.

Comment: not work at all

Comment: Very sorry. I did a mistake

Comment: Hi Hantsy, I know my question below does not fit with this topic but I still want to ask you that:
Do you have any example about Spring Webflux multi-tenancy using Keycloak?