# R2DBC spring postgres enum mapping

Tags: postgresql, enums, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I'm new to spring r2dbc. Previously I've user hibernate. In hibernate when you need to map postgresql enum to java enum you just add `com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52` and use `@Enumerated` (as shown bellow). Related to [R2DBC and enum (PostgreSQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60084867/r2dbc-and-enum-postgresql) SO question I have to create codec for every single enum. Is it possible to achive this with some kind of tag or other general solution not just creating multiple codecs.

```sql
CREATE TYPE user_type_enum AS ENUM ('ADMIN', 'USER');
```

```java
public class PostgreSQLEnumType extends org.hibernate.type.EnumType {
  public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value,
      int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
      throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    st.setObject(
      index,
      value != null ? ((Enum) value).name() : null,
      Types.OTHER
    );
  }
}
```

```java
public enum UserTypeEnum {
  ADMIN,
  USER
}
```

```java
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;

@Table;
@TypeDef(
    name = "pgsql_enum",
    typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class
)
public class User {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String usename;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Type(type = "pgsql_enum")
  private UserEnumType userType;

  // Getters and setters provided
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create your own codecs anymore.
See https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql#postgres-enum-types

DDL:

```
CREATE TYPE my_enum AS ENUM ('FIRST', 'SECOND');
```

Java Enum class:

```java
enum MyEnumType {
  FIRST, SECOND;
}
```

Your R2DBC ConnectionFactory bean:

```java
PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
.codecRegistrar(EnumCodec.builder()
.withEnum("my_enum",MyEnumType.class)
.build());
```

Note that you must use lower case letter for your `"my_enum"` in `withEnum`, otherwise won't work.

Also, you will need to provide a converter that extends EnumWriteSupport, and register it.
See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.explicit.enum.converters

For example:

```
@Configuration
public static class R2DBCConfiguration extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {
        @Override
        @Bean
        public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Object> getCustomConverters() {
            return List.of(
                new MyEnumTypeConverter()
            );
        }
    }
```